# Entry point error in suitescript, How i fix it?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Im trying to display a confirmation message when a record is correctly saved and an error message when its not.

But when I try to save the script I get

> SuiteScript 2.x entry point scripts must implement one script type function

appears and i don't know why. Here is the script:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 *
 */


 define('[N/ui/message]', function(message){

    function saveRecord(context){
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;

        var pName = currentRecord.getValue('name');
        var pAge = currentRecord.getValue('custrecord_p_age');
        var pLastName = currentRecord.getValue('custrecord_plastname');

    if(pName != null && pAge != null && pLastName != null ){

      var confirmationMsg = message.create({
          title: 'Enhorabuena',
          message: 'La persona ah sido ingresada con exito',
          Type: message.Type.CONFIRMATION
      });

      confirmationMsg.show({
          duration: 5000
      });

      return true;

    }else{

        var errorMsg = message.create({
            title: 'Enhorabuena',
            message: 'La persona ah sido ingresada con exito',
            Type: message.Type.ERROR
        });

        errorMsg.show({
            duration: 5000
        });

        return false;

        }
    }

    return{
        saveRecord: saveRecord
    }

  });
```

Comment: your dependencies should be listed an array of strings instead of a string. i.e. `['N/ui/message']` .  If you write it as a string then netsuite will use it as an id and expect the second argument to be the dependencies Array.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
/** *@NApiVersion 2.x *@NScriptType ClientScript * */
```

to (remove the extra * towards the end of the tag)

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
```

Also change

```
define('[N/ui/message]', function(message){
```

to  (move the single quotes to inside the brackets)

```
define(['N/ui/message'], function(message){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a stripped down version in the debugger with "Require." Your code seems fine. Also write it in Visual Code so you can see the formatting. Take out the functionality and see what is missing in structure for suitescript 2.0, example:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 */
define(["N/log"], function(log) {
  function dostuff(context) {
    //do stuff
  }
  return {
    post: dostuff
  };
```

});

Comment: the debugger is more akin to server-side.  it would make more sense to open the devtools of your browser and try this (caveat: you have to be on a netsuite page where `require` is exposed and  logged in).  But perhaps you could include an example that matches your suggestion?  thirdly, log is not a great example since it's in the global scope all the time.  lastly, your code block needs to be fixed to be correct -- you've dangled the closing parens outside the markdown fences.